# Ubuntu 20.04 WiFi drops out sporadically (dmesg output inside)?

Tags: networking, wireless, 20.04, internet

My Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS installation works fine, except that WiFi (which works well otherwise) sporadically drops out. Here is the `dmesg` output from the most recent dropout I've had:

```
[25292.667030] wlp58s0: deauthenticating from c0:56:27:77:16:79 by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[25301.806245] wlp58s0: authenticate with c0:56:27:77:16:78
[25301.850424] wlp58s0: send auth to c0:56:27:77:16:78 (try 1/3)
[25301.871722] wlp58s0: authenticated
[25301.871912] wlp58s0: associating with AP with corrupt probe response
[25301.874938] wlp58s0: associate with c0:56:27:77:16:78 (try 1/3)
[25301.905032] wlp58s0: RX AssocResp from c0:56:27:77:16:78 (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=6)
[25301.907899] wlp58s0: associated
[25301.913471] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp58s0: link becomes ready
[25333.806902] pcieport 0000:00:1c.4: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:00:1c.4
[25333.806917] pcieport 0000:00:1c.4: AER: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Data Link Layer, (Transmitter ID)
[25333.806927] pcieport 0000:00:1c.4: AER:   device [8086:9d14] error status/mask=00001000/00002000
[25333.806934] pcieport 0000:00:1c.4: AER:    [12] Timeout               
[25392.664477] kauditd_printk_skb: 31 callbacks suppressed
[25392.664480] audit: type=1400 audit(1601248771.424:43): apparmor="DENIED" operation="capable" profile="/usr/sbin/cups-browsed" pid=31832 comm="cups-browsed" capability=23  capname="sys_nice"
[25479.092532] audit: type=1400 audit(1601248857.852:44): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/cupsd" name="/etc/magic" pid=32343 comm="file" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=7 ouid=0
[25921.889359] pcieport 0000:00:1c.4: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:00:1c.4
[25921.889367] pcieport 0000:00:1c.4: AER: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Data Link Layer, (Transmitter ID)
[25921.889371] pcieport 0000:00:1c.4: AER:   device [8086:9d14] error status/mask=00001000/00002000
[25921.889374] pcieport 0000:00:1c.4: AER:    [12] Timeout               
[26206.115583] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: failed to receive scan abortion completion: timed out
[26206.115595] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: failed to stop scan: -110
[26206.115600] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: failed to start hw scan: -110
[26385.067565] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: wmi command 12289 timeout, restarting hardware
[26385.067580] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: failed to start hw scan: -11
[26385.098112] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: failed to read hi_board_data address: -16
[26388.139151] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: failed to receive initialized event from target: 00000000
[26391.174854] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: failed to receive initialized event from target: 00000000
[26391.174859] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: failed to wait for target init: -110
[26391.176759] ieee80211 phy3: Hardware restart was requested
[26391.400851] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: unsupported HTC service id: 1536
[26391.484637] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: device successfully recovered
[26391.582133] wlp58s0: deauthenticated from c0:56:27:77:16:78 (Reason: 7=CLASS3_FRAME_FROM_NONASSOC_STA)
[26391.698284] wlp58s0: authenticate with c0:56:27:77:16:78
[26391.752178] wlp58s0: send auth to c0:56:27:77:16:78 (try 1/3)
[26391.754088] wlp58s0: authenticated
[26391.754277] wlp58s0: associating with AP with corrupt probe response
[26391.759715] wlp58s0: associate with c0:56:27:77:16:78 (try 1/3)
[26391.798081] wlp58s0: RX AssocResp from c0:56:27:77:16:78 (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=6)
[26391.800730] wlp58s0: associated
[26464.202540] pcieport 0000:00:1c.4: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:00:1c.4
[26464.202549] pcieport 0000:00:1c.4: AER: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Data Link Layer, (Transmitter ID)
[26464.202553] pcieport 0000:00:1c.4: AER:   device [8086:9d14] error status/mask=00001000/00002000
[26464.202556] pcieport 0000:00:1c.4: AER:    [12] Timeout               
[26491.751444] pcieport 0000:00:1c.4: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:00:1c.4
[26491.751451] pcieport 0000:00:1c.4: AER: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Data Link Layer, (Transmitter ID)
[26491.751455] pcieport 0000:00:1c.4: AER:   device [8086:9d14] error status/mask=00001000/00002000
[26491.751459] pcieport 0000:00:1c.4: AER:    [12] Timeout               
[26491.798436] pcieport 0000:00:1c.4: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:00:1c.4
[26491.798445] pcieport 0000:00:1c.4: AER: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Data Link Layer, (Transmitter ID)
[26491.798450] pcieport 0000:00:1c.4: AER:   device [8086:9d14] error status/mask=00001000/00002000
[26491.798453] pcieport 0000:00:1c.4: AER:    [12] Timeout               
[26493.162224] pcieport 0000:00:1c.4: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:00:1c.4
[26493.162231] pcieport 0000:00:1c.4: AER: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Data Link Layer, (Transmitter ID)
[26493.162235] pcieport 0000:00:1c.4: AER:   device [8086:9d14] error status/mask=00001000/00002000
[26493.162237] pcieport 0000:00:1c.4: AER:    [12] Timeout               
[26493.444437] pcieport 0000:00:1c.4: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:00:1c.4
[26493.444446] pcieport 0000:00:1c.4: AER: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Data Link Layer, (Transmitter ID)
[26493.444450] pcieport 0000:00:1c.4: AER:   device [8086:9d14] error status/mask=00001000/00002000
[26493.444454] pcieport 0000:00:1c.4: AER:    [12] Timeout               
[26631.026195] wacom 0005:056A:0377.0009: unknown main item tag 0x0
[26631.026769] input: Wacom Intuos BT S Pen as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:2/0005:056A:0377.0009/input/input52
[26631.027432] input: Wacom Intuos BT S Pad as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:2/0005:056A:0377.0009/input/input54
[26631.028234] wacom 0005:056A:0377.0009: hidraw4: BLUETOOTH HID v0.00 Device [Intuos BT S] on 9c:b6:d0:e3:5d:96
[26757.047220] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: failed to receive scan abortion completion: timed out
[26757.047224] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: failed to stop scan: -110
[26757.047226] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: failed to start hw scan: -110
```

Can anyone see something here, which could indicate the issue? Note that I can restore WiFi by running:

```
$ sudo rmmod ath10k_pci && sudo modprobe ath10k_pci
```

Which indicates a kernel issue to me... I'd of course like to fix this, so that I don't have sporadic WiFi dropouts (especially if it happens during phone calls). My wireless card is (Dell XPS 9360, late 2017):

```
$ sudo lshw -C network
  *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
```

Comment: Check your wifi router/access-point. If it's set to some sort of 'auto-channel' setting, change it to a fixed channel setting. You can see an example of it helping the 'deauthenticating by local choice' [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/243280/how-to-fix-deauthentication-by-local-choice).

Comment: Hmm that seems to be what's causing the error - but it didn't use to happen in 18.04, with the same router/access-point. Since I can't figure out how to re-configure my router - is there a way to fix the issue from the Ubuntu side?

Comment: I can't think of a way to do it OS-side. Look up your router's name and there's likely a configuration panel on a local website, something like https://192.168.1.255/admin/ or the likes. Your ISP may require a password, if they supplied it. Their service department can help you out. It's often the same password for all customers, so the internet may well have that data.

Comment: I've had this same thing happen on Ubuntu 20.04 on a Lenovo T490 and PopOS 20.10 on a Dell XPS 13. All other devices on my home router do not experience drop-outs like this. I've read up on the multiple "fixes" but none seem to work. I do have my router set to auto for channel but the drops continued even when I had the channels set specifically. Still looking for that elusive solution that works.

Comment: select a wifi channel which is not in use. to see channels in use around you type in terminal      nmcli d wifi list

Comment: I tried setting the static channel manually on my router (WRT1900acs) to apparently available channels (using LinSSID).  The drop out always comes back and no other devices (Macs, mobile, Roku, etc) show any indication of drops.

Comment: channel may be occupied by someone when connection dropped, see if there is interference when drop.

Comment: I've looked for that but if it was interference on the router end of things, wouldn't all devices on the wireless experience the same?  As far as I can tell, my Linux laptops are the only things seeing the drop.  I appreciate the help!

Comment: In my laptop i unchecked wireless power saving features in laptop mode tools configuration

Comment: see this 4o Mhz (BW Mhz)  https://www.bitfeed.co/page/wifi-20-mhz-or-40-mhz-how-to-choose-the-bandwidth

Comment: Installed laptop tools config and tried disabling wireless power saving. No luck. Router is set to auto-bandwidth so it should switch between 20/40 MHz depending on how crowded the field is in my area.  Honestly, it's not too bad. I'm convinced the network/router is not part of the issue.

Comment: check in linssid if it is 40 or 20 in bw mhz.

Comment: I'm testing the ideas here: https://support.system76.com/articles/wireless/ Will see if any of these help.

Comment: @SteveH Good luck but I will just say that if you look at my own answer to this question, I ended up opening up my laptop and switching to a physically different WiFi card. The issue for me was really in the hardware and no software solution helped (I tinkered.... a lot).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/974033/512940) solved my problem, which required only a Ubuntu-side change and no tinkering with routers. Basically the `REGDOMAIN` variable was empty, and I needed to set it to `US` via:

```
sudo iw reg set US
sudo sed -i 's/^REG.*=$/&US/' /etc/default/crda
```

I have not experienced WiFi dropouts in a week now, versus the previous approx 1 day between dropouts.

**UPDATE**

Experienced the same dropout again! Applied the fix of disabling IPv6 in `/etc/default/grub`:

```
#Change the line:
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="<stuff>"
# To:
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="<stuff> ipv6.disable=1"
```

and run `sudo update-grub`. I'll report back here if I spot similar dropouts.

**UPDATE 2 (solution)**

I ended up still seeing dropouts... No "software only" solution ended up working for me. What worked was to replace the WiFi card with the [Intel Wireless-Ac 9260](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B079QH5KW1). I came upon this solution via the [Arch Linux docs for Dell XPS 9360](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dell_XPS_13_(9360)#Wireless).